# predict continuous variable over time for each row

Tags: r, regression, time-series, survival, prediction

I have many items with a start date, which produce continuous outputs over time for a few months after the start date. These outputs often follow a decay function but not always. So it is a bit like a survival analysis problem. But rather than predicting a probability over time I need to predict a continuous value over time (resolution month). Which (machine learning) modelling could I use for this please? Thanks!

Comment: would you please post a link to an example that clearly has a decay-like function?

Comment: @JamesPhillips - the values do not always follow a decay function. But if you ask for what a decay function, I googled an example for you: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialDecay.html

Comment: Your generously googled data example cannot help answer the question regarding your specific data.

Comment: @JamesPhillips you must understand that one cannot always upload data here. imho the problem is quite well described.